# Como puedo seleccionar todos los check con un solo botón, Visual Basic 6.0 MSFlexGrid

Tags: vb6

```
Option Explicit

Dim strChecked As String


Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim i As Variant, ms_rows As Integer
    ' Start building the Grid

ms_rows = 20 ' This is the number of rows to print out
With MSFlexGrid1
        .Row = 0
        .Col = 0
        .Rows = ms_rows + 1  'We add 1 to ensure we get all the rows
        .Cols = 2
        .ColWidth(0) = 250 ' CheckBox column
        .ColWidth(1) = 1440 ' Index column
End With

' Now build the Grid

For i = 0 To 20 'm_rows - 1
     With MSFlexGrid1
          .Row = i: .Col = 0: .CellPictureAlignment = 4 ' Align the checkbox
          Set .CellPicture = picUnchecked.Picture  ' Set the default checkbox picture to the empty box
          .TextMatrix(i, 1) = i
     End With
Next
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_Click()
Dim oldx, oldy, cell2text As String, strTextCheck As String

' Check or uncheck the grid checkbox
With MSFlexGrid1
    oldx = .Col
    oldy = .Row
        If MSFlexGrid1.Col = 0 Then
            If MSFlexGrid1.CellPicture = picChecked Then
                Set MSFlexGrid1.CellPicture = picUnchecked
                .Col = .Col + 1  ' I use data that is in column #1, usually an Index or ID #
                strTextCheck = .Text
                ' When you de-select a CheckBox, we need to strip out the #
                strChecked = Replace(strChecked, strTextCheck & ",", "")
                ' Don't forget to strip off the trailing , before passing the string
                Debug.Print strChecked
            Else
                Set MSFlexGrid1.CellPicture = picChecked
                .Col = .Col + 1
                strTextCheck = .Text
                strChecked = strChecked & strTextCheck & ","
                Debug.Print strChecked
            End If
        End If
    .Col = oldx
    .Row = oldy
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta.. el codigo ya hace eso que vos decis.. cual es el problema?

Comment: puedo seleccionar por separado, lo que quiero es con un botón seleccionar todo.

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que estas pidiendo.. esta en tu codigo.. solo hay que entender que hace ese codigo que marca uno. y hacer que marque todos.

Donde el codigo dice que arma la grilla, no esta haciendo otra cosa que "desmarcando" todos los elementos.

Por lo tanto, podemos tomar esa parte:

```
For i = 0 To 20
    ...
next
```

Ahora, adentro, lo unico que tenemos que hacer es cambiar el picture que se usa para que este desmarcado, como marcado

Eso lo esta haciendo para un solo elemento aca:

```
With MSFlexGrid1
    .Row = i 
    .Col = 0 
    Set .CellPicture = picUnchecked.Picture
```

Asi, que aprovechando estas dos cosas, podrias hacer:

```
For i = 0 To 20
    With MSFlexGrid1
        .Row = i 
        .Col = 0 
        Set .CellPicture = picChecked
    end with
next
```